# Looking for javascript to split URI

Tags: javascript, urlsplit

Here is my URI.

```
/v1/securemessages/members/{mbruid}?folder=Inbox
```

I want to split this URI using javascript and pass the value of mbruid to a stored procedure.

Here is my script.

```
function getQueryParam(encUrl,pathverIndex){

    var url,reqURIParam;
    url=decodeURIComponent(encUrl);
    pathVarArr = url.split('/');
    reqURIParam =pathVarArr[pathverIndex];
    return reqURIParam;
}

mbruid = getQueryParam(tags["encURL"],4);
```

The problem is that I am getting `{mbruid}?folder=Inbox` instead of `{mbruid}`. Please help me modify my script so the only desired variable is returned.

Comment: you might want to use a uri library.

Comment: `return reqURIParam.split('?').shift()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways to do this but here's one specific to your url:

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/bawuvu/2/edit?js,console)

```
var x = url.split('?')[0].split('/').splice(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var uri = "/v1/securemessages/members/{mbruid}?folder=Inbox",
   data = uri.match(/[^/]*(?=\?)/)[0];
```

Explanation as follows

```
[^/]*(?=\?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/z2aYG64umEGYZmCA)

Answer (score 0):

One way would to do something like:

```
var foo = url.split('/');
var test = foo[4].split('?')
test[0] // {bruid}
```